# How to make a vertical LimitLine in MPhil chart

Tags: android, graph

I want to accomplish the following thing.

I have a chart (MPhil) with distance and speed.
As of now it is possible to click on any point in the graph and then it is shown in my Google maps. However, I would like to do the following thing now. I want to have a vertical line (this yellow line which is already visible when clicking on that point) that is draggable. With this vertical line I can move through the graph and whenever it touches a point this point should be drawn in the map.

Here is a picture of what I have accomplished so far

[image]

I hope I described it as good as possible?

Maybe somebody has any hint for me?

Thanks in advance!